# Xcode 6 Beta 6 if statement: bool is not convertible to UInt8

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a tic tac toe game according to the fifth tutorial by Skip Wilson on youtube. However, I'm using beta 6 and he's using one of the earlier ones in the video. Though taking all the same steps as him, I get an error to this code:

```
if (!plays[sender.tag] && !aiDeciding && !done != nil){
    setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
}
```

It says:

> bool is not convertible to UInt8.

The error points to "done" on the first line of code. done is a variable with a value of false when it enters the if. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry the question is unclear. im a new user and im not exactly sure how to make the code view thing

Comment: What variable type is done?

Comment: If `done` is a boolean why are you testing its equality/inequality?  Just use booleans directly or with `!`

Answer (score 1):

*In Objective-C and in previous versions of Swift you could use another type than Bool, like if an int is 0 is translates to false, and if an object is nil it is also false.*

---

Use something like that (syntax is correct):

```
struct Sender {// just to simulate the notation of sender.tag without using a UIView
    var tag = 1
}
var plays: [Int : Int] = [1 : 2, 3 : 4] // example values
var aiDeciding: Bool = true
var done: Bool = false
var sender: Sender = Sender()

if plays[sender.tag] == nil && aiDeciding == false && done == false {
    print("works") // will NOT be called in the situation with the example values
}
```

Instead of `done == false` you can use `!done`. But since you are having problems I thought I should write it out. And I like it that way too.

Comment: doesnt seem to work. plays is a dictionary with <int, int>, aiDeciding is a boolean and done is also a boolean

Comment: @AarniAlasaarela It worked, but it wasn't the right types for you. So now I changed it to your types and tested it. Added to answer.